# Adding legend to bar chart with data from two data frames

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have two plots I just want to know how I can add a legend for the blue and gray bar charts and also could you please show me how you could also edit the legend tittle.

```
X1 <- c(seq(7.912087912,44.83516484,1.538461538))
X2 <- c(seq(7.912087912,49.45054945,1.538461538))

dat2 <- data.frame(x = X2 , y = rnorm(28, 26, 5))

dat1 <- data.frame(x = X1 , y =  rnorm(100, 25, 4))

ggplot(NULL)  +
  geom_bar(dat1, mapping = aes(x = x, y = y), stat = "identity",alpha = 0.3, position = "stack" ) + labs( x = " Time [ S ]", y = "Frequency") + theme_minimal() +
  ggtitle("Histogram Of Time In Tank") + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  geom_bar(dat2, mapping = aes(x = x, y = y  ), stat = "identity", alpha = .3, position = "stack", fill='lightblue' , color='lightblue4')  
+ scale_linetype_discrete(name = LegendTitle)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a legend in ggplot, you need to have an aesthetic mapping inside your `aes()` or no legend will appear. Here's how we can set a mapping and then use the scale to set the colors we want

```
ggplot(NULL)  +
  geom_bar(dat1, mapping = aes(x = x, y = y, fill="Grey Bars"), stat = "identity",alpha = 0.3, position = "stack" ) + 
  labs( x = " Time [ S ]", y = "Frequency") + 
  theme_minimal() +
  ggtitle("Histogram Of Time In Tank") + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  geom_bar(dat2, mapping = aes(x = x, y = y, fill='Blue Bars') , stat = "identity", alpha = .3, position = "stack", color='lightblue4')  +
  scale_fill_manual(name="Bars", values=c("Grey Bars" = "grey35", "Blue Bars" = "lightblue"))
```

[image: Bar plot with fill legend]